# How to serve up server data to webflow site using javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, api

I've successfully received API data using my node server and now I want to display it on my webflow site. I can do this easily enough with a local index.html client but how to do it when it's a remote client hosted on webflow? What client side javacript do I need to add in the webflow code block to display the console logged data?
Here is my node js code. Thanks for any help.

```
        const Blockfrost = require('@blockfrost/blockfrost-js');

    const API = new Blockfrost.BlockFrostAPI({
      projectId: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
    });

    const PAGE_SIZE = 100 /* 100 is the max Blockfrost page size */
    const stake_address = 'stake1';

    async function count_assets() {
      let total = 0;
      try {
        let page = 1;
        let assets = [];
        // Retrieve assets as long as pages are full
        do {
          assets = await API.accountsAddressesAssets(
            stake_address,
            { page: page, count: PAGE_SIZE, order: 'asc' }
          );
          total += assets.length;
          page++;
        } while (assets.length == PAGE_SIZE);
      } catch (err) {
        console.log('error', err);
      }
      return total;
    }

    count_assets(stake_address).then(assets => {
      console.log(stake_address, 'assets:', assets);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use JQuery to get the data from your node.js app on webflow.
Write the code in the before  tag of the page:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "https://dummyjson.com/products/1",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data) {
      $(".div-block").append(
        "<p>" + data.title + " - " + data.price + "</p>"
      );
    },
    error: function(error) {
      console.log("An error occurred: " + error);
    }
  });
});
```

You can find more documentations on how to get() or post() data from/to your node.js app on https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ajax_get_post.asp